# Android findViewWithTag for views with multiple tags

Tags: android

I used to set a tag to a view using `view.setTag(t1);` and then get the view using `parent.findViewWithTag(t1);` which returned correctly.

I now need to set 2 different tags for my views and I am doing that using

```
view.setTag(R.id.tag1, t1);
view.setTag(R.id.tag2, t2);
```

Where tag1 and tag2 are ids declared in res/values/ids.xml

I am then trying to get the view with tag t1, but `parent.findViewWithTag(t1);` returns null. I searched and there is no method `findViewWithTag` or similar that would also accept the key of the tag.

Is there any way to achieve this? If there isn't could you point me to where it's stated in the android documentation?

In this specific case, I could use `id` instead of one of the tags, but for situations where that is not possible, I would like to know if it can be achieved using tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`findViewWithTag(tag)` returns the View with the default tag set by `setTag(tag)` as compared using `tag.equals(getTag())`.

Answer (score 2):

as a complement to Diegos answer I would like to point it out on the source code:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/View.java#18288

```
if (tag != null && tag.equals(mTag)) {
```

the tag used to compare and find the view is the `mTag` which is set by using the direct method `setTag(Object)` as seen on the source code on this line:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/View.java#18505

```
public void setTag(final Object tag) {
    mTag = tag;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The methods `View.getTag()` or `View.findViewWithTag()` will only return the `Object` assigned by `View.setTag()` to a certain `View`, see also the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html).

However, you can write your own `findViewWithTag()` method:

```
public View findViewWithTag(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int tagID, @NonNull Object myTag) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++)
    {
        View v = parent.getChildAt(i);
        if ( myTag.equals(v.getTag(tagID)) )
        {
            return v;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

You can also narrow down the search to specific subclasses of `View` by adding some condition like `(v instanceof MySpecificView)` to the `if` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Find recursively all views with specific tag:

```
fun ViewGroup.findViewsWithTag(tagResId: Int, outList: ArrayList<View>) {
    val tagString = getString(tagResId)
    return findViewsWithTag(tagString, outList)
}

fun ViewGroup.findViewsWithTag(tagString: String, outArrayList: ArrayList<View>) {
    for (i in 0 until childCount) {
        val view = getChildAt(i)

        if (view.tag == tagString) {
            outArrayList.add(view)
        }

        if (view is ViewGroup) {
            view.findViewsWithTag(tagString, outArrayList)
        }
    }
}
```